# Spingfox not recognizing custom serializer when generating JSON model for swagger

Tags: java, json, swagger, jhipster, springfox

My jhipster v2.23.1 app uses custom serializers and deserializers for JSON parsing which I register as a module in `JacksonConfiguration`.  The REST API works as expected using my custom mapping.

However, the JSON displayed in the auto-generated swagger documentation doesn't reflect the custom mapping.  I was hoping swagger would detect custom serializers/deserializers automatically, but since it doesn't, how can I get swagger to show my custom JSON format instead of the one it detects on its own?

Based on the springfox documentation at http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#configuring-springfox i've implemented the interface:

```
ApplicationListener<ObjectMapperConfigured>
```

in my SwaggerConfiguration bean.  I can see that the `onApplicationEvent(ObjectMapperConfigured event)` method is called twice.  The first time the mapper will serialize my object as expected, the second time it will not.  It also doesn't seem to make a difference if I register my module with the mapper or not.  The object I'm working with here is a Contact.

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ObjectMapperConfigured event) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = event.getObjectMapper();

    // Custom serialization for Contact objects
    SimpleModule contactModule = new SimpleModule("Contact Module");
    contactModule.addSerializer(new ContactSerializer(Contact.class));
    contactModule.addDeserializer(Contact.class, new ContactDeserializer(Contact.class));

    mapper.registerModule(contactModule);

    // My custom object
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.setCity("Springfield");
    c.setEmail("someone@gmail.com");

    String contactJsonStr = null;
    try {
        contactJsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(c);
    } catch(JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Serialized Contact: " + contactJsonStr);
}
```

How can I get springfox to use my custom serializer in order to build my swagger documentation?  Or should I be using a different approach entirely?

Comment: You should ask springfox project

Comment: @GaëlMarziou It was asked twice, but nothing done about it, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1753 https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1639

Comment: Then you should contribute it

Answer (score 3):

Hey I know this is an old question but i stumbled uppon the same problem and done a little research.

The solution is quite simple. Write a class wich represents your custom serialized object. Then just use the [directModelSubstitute](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/current/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#directModelSubstitute(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)) method in your Docket method to substitute your original model class with the serialized model.

If your serializer does something like this to serialise the DateTime into UNIX Time (Long)

```
public void serialize(final DateTime value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        long millis = value.getMillis();
        gen.writeNumber(millis);
}
```

Just add `.directModelSubstitute(DateTime.class, Long.class)` this line to your Docket definition.