# Springfox support for custom @JsonSerialize

Tags: json, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have a wrapper class with a field that is using custom Serializer and Deserializer.

```
public class Policy {

    @JsonSerialize(using = PolicyDurationSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PolicyDurationDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty
    @Nullable
    private PolicyDuration duration;

...
```

Also `PolicyDuration` class wraps a field `Duration` type

```
public class PolicyDuration {
    @Nonnull
    private Duration duration;

    public PolicyDuration(@Nonnull Duration duration) {
        this.duration = roundPolicyDuration(duration);
    }
    ...
```

Now, the custom serializer is

```
public class PolicyDurationSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PolicyDuration> {

    public void serialize(PolicyDuration value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (value != null) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();

            jgen.writeNumberField("amount", hours);
            jgen.writeStringField("unit", ChronoUnit.HOURS.name());

            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }

    }
}
```

Springfox is printing an empty object in `duration` field.

```
"duration": {}
```

And I would like it to show the structure of the custom object I've created:

```
"duration": {
   "amount": 1440,
   "unit": "MINUTES"
}
```

Is there any way to configure Springfox to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spingfox not recognizing custom serializer when generating JSON model for swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728778/spingfox-not-recognizing-custom-serializer-when-generating-json-model-for-swagge)

Comment: @pvpkiran I'm sorry, but it's not valid. For other cases where an existing object or type (String, Long, CustomObject...) is returned, it can be valid. In my case, I am returning a JSON object that does not exist in Java as either a POJO or a class.